# How to select tr by property value in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to find a tr by its property rowIndex is equals to some specific value.
rowIndex is not a attribute

I tried following,

```
$(table).find('tr[rowIndex = 1]')
```

but no luck

Please help

Comment: Can you add `HTML` code also. Also highlight the element to select

Comment: I need to find, tr where RowIndex = "somevalue". But rowIndex is not a attribute in tr. It is a element of Jquery tr object.  $(table).find('tr')[i].rowIndex

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `table` in quotes to select `<table>` element.

```
$('table').find('tr[rowIndex = 1]')
```

You can also select element using

```
$('table tr[rowIndex=1]')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the first `tr` child of a table then use `first-child`

```
$('table').find('tr:first-child')
```

If you want to filter based on a dom property(not element attribute) then

```
$('table').find('tr').filter(function () {
    return this.rowIndex == 1
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :eq()

```
$('table').find('tr:eq(1)')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can find by

```js
   $('table tr').filter("[rowIndex=1]");
```

this also..!

Comment: This sets the `rowIndex` to one

Comment: @Tushar you r right dear sorry for what answered in eagerness